# Email updates arrive later and later

Tags: bug, email-notification

When you subscribe to a tag you get email updates for that tags. It seems that these updates start to arrive around the time you made the subscription the next day if you have it set to update every day. However, I have noticed that the updates over time arrive later and later. For example, some months ago (e.g. 2012-10) I got updates for [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) around midnight but currently they arrive during the afternoon and earlier this year I got them around lunch. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's a feature! But I _am_ curious why you would classify this as a bug. As far as I know, there is no expectations for these to come in at the same time every day.

Comment: @Oded Well. No *stated* expectations, but it'd be *logical*, wouldn't it? (But I agree, not a bug as such).

Comment: @J.Steen - Well, I'd expect it to drift. Considering that over time there would be more subscriptions to more tags, a job that would send emails would also have more data to go through and take longer to send them.

Comment: @Oded Of course. But a drift of over 12 hours? If I had created the function, I'd start to worry. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - I'd expect that the job schedule has also changed over time, to coincide with the less busy hours of the site.

Comment: @Oded I assumed that if you choose to get notifications every day that would mean to get notifications every day around the time you subscribed to the tag. I guess this is what a user would assume but if one is aware of the implementation details the increased work load for processing notifications causing drift makes sense but it is strange if users should have to think like that. Maybe it would make sense to let the user choose the time to get the notification when the user chooses notifications every day?

Comment: @Oded Excellent point. As hard as that would be, with today's rather international crowd. =)

Comment: @N.N. - I'd expect a daily notification. I wouldn't expect it to be at the same time every day.